# StackOverflowError on HashMap.hash for Lombok Hibernate Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, lombok

I'm trying to make spring boot application. i want to get set of goals for each user. But i receive the error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:552) ~[na:na e.t.c.
```

In Goal:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private User userss;
```

In User:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userss", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Set<Goal> goalSet = new HashSet<>();
```

And method for receiving goals for each user:

```
@Override
public Set findByUserId(Long userId){
   return (Set) getSession().createQuery("from Goal where userss.id =:userId").setParameter("userId", userId).stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

And method for receiving all users with their goals:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Set getGoals() {
    return (Set) getSession().createQuery("from Goal").stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

I use lombok for hash (and actually for other basic methods)

Comment: Some `hashCode()` method is recursive. Possibly indirectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Lombok for your entity, you must limit the generator

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true) // important
public class User {

    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include // important, only on the PK
    UUID id;

    // Other fields not included in the generator
}
```

This is because, by default, Lombok generates the methods Equals and HashCode for every fields of your entity, but Hibernate requires the equality to be only done on the `@Id` field.

You have to do this for all your Entities.

**Why was it crashing?**

Because Goal references User, and User references Goal; when the default generator implemented Equals and HashCode, it would call both instances back and forth infinitely, until the crash.

Even without such cyclic references, Hibernate wouldn't know how to handle the entities in its cache without a proper Equals and HashCode.

You may need a similar limitation for `@ToString` to prevent recursive infinite loops.